# Incorrect Uniswap Liquidity Calculations. What could be wrong?

Tags: contract-debugging, uniswap, bug, dapp-debugging, liquidity-provider

Looking though a uniswap address: https://info.uniswap.org/account/0xd62317c76E626D53C900088Fb07539b829B564B2

This address shows that it added $30k+ worth of liquidity, and none of it is removed. Why is the liquidity total on top only showing $23k. Is this a uniswap bug or an ethereum bug? And how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bug. This [address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd62317c76e626d53c900088fb07539b829b564b2#tokentxns) holds exactly 0 liquidity token for the wOxen-USDT pair. Accordingly, [Uniswap info](https://info.uniswap.org/account/0xd62317c76E626D53C900088Fb07539b829B564B2) shows 0$ as liquidity provided.

How come, you may ask, since $30K+ were provided as liquidity to that pair?

Well, the liquidity tokens were staked! Staking involves transferring the uniswap liquidity tokens to another address: [this one](http://0x66D17A3D12A6D7D1f06E30f91E0Cac47F2fB6937), as a matter of facts (see [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x08a7c56a0324c04772e0030cfa86dc121d64e768b5ed7ff42c062c4cdfaa7747)). If they are held by another address, they are no longer in your account.

If you did stake those liquidity tokens, unstake them and you should see them back under your address and on the Uniswap info page.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think crypto is safe but there is some bug when displaying it, try a refresh or manually check it with solidity or etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an Impermanent Loss issue. I'll try to give a brief description, but you should really read up on it - it's critical to understanding the risks of being a liquidity provider.

Basically, if the price of an asset in a LP changes outside the pool (like the exchange price), then an arbitrage situation occurs. This can cause the ratio of assets in the pool to change. As the pool is arbitraged (and ratio altered), the value of the liquidity is recalculated based on the new ratio of assets.

In even shorter, your deposits to an LP can lose value depending on how the market moves.

[Finematics](https://finematics.com/impermanent-loss-explained/) has a great explainer, and links to [article](https://pintail.medium.com/uniswap-a-good-deal-for-liquidity-providers-104c0b6816f2), which is also a very good read on the subject.

Comment: For the record, "impermanent loss" is a new term in something very classical and well understood in finance. The concept is called Replicating Portfolio on constant product markets. All medium article calculations stem from this paper: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3550601